# ¿Cómo achicar imagen en django antes de subir al servidor?

Tags: django-models

Buenas, el sistema sube las imágenes sin ningún problema.
La cuestión es que antes de que se guarde en el servidor quiero achicar la imagen, para no tener que decirle al usuario que la imagen debe ser >=X tamaño, ya que veo engorroso el hecho de pedirle que la achique, el usuario no tiene por que saber achicar imágenes para usar el sistema.
Saludos...

Comment: cuando hablas de achicar es peso o tamaño ?

Comment: si, reducir el peso, aunque esto disminuya la calidad de la imagen. La idea es que no se archiven o alojen con un peso tan grande en el servidor. Gracias de antemano...Saludos